# Un-ignoring a file in an ignored directory in git

Tags: git

In my `.gititnore` I have an entry:

```
/build
```

Which works well- the entire directory is ignored by git. Now, I just want to make an exception to this rule and keep this file `/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt` in git.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current rule for gitignore is

[**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)

That means:

- you need to ignore all the *files* recursively: that is '`**`'
- exclude all the *folders* recursively: those are '`**/`'
- exclude the file you want (which will work because its parent folder is not ignored as well)

Result:

```
/build/**
!/build/**/
!/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```

Check what is and is not ignored with [`git check-ignore -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) (the `-v` is important):

```
git check-ignore -v -- afile
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, the gitignore rules are tricky. I just tested this answer, and it works. git 2.8.1

Comment: great answer + great explanation! Just adapted your answer to my new use case